# When I will see the weak localization effect?

Tags: anderson-localization

I understand the origin of weak localization (WL) effect but I have a doubt that when I will see the WL effect, assuming that I am at low temperature and I have quasi 2D sample.

Comment: Please add more information. Which system are you interested in? What do you mean be "when" (... when I will see the WL effect) and what by "see"?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that what are the condition to observe weak localization in the sample. Will I be able to see the weak localization in every 2D sample at low enough temperatures (<2K)?